# Synchronize JTextFields Values by PropertyChangeListener

Tags: java, swing

I want to copy the value of a `jTextField - TXTFLD1` to another `jTextField -TXTFLD2` when the value at TXTFLD1 changes. 
I choose `propertychangelistener` because i cannot detect when the value at TXTFLD1 is changed, Because it is changed by some external code which i cannot modify now.

The test code is as follows :

```
public class TxtFldSync extends JFrame {
    private JButton BTN1 = null;
    private JTextField TXTFLD1 = null;
    private JTextField TXTFLD2 = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            TxtFldSync thisClass = new TxtFldSync();
            thisClass.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            thisClass.setVisible(true);
    }
    public TxtFldSync() {
        super();
        this.setSize(300, 200);
        BTN1 = new JButton();
        BTN1.setBounds(new Rectangle(178, 38, 67, 17));
        TXTFLD1 = new JTextField();
        TXTFLD1.setBounds(new Rectangle(32, 42, 83, 20));

        TXTFLD2 = new JTextField();
        TXTFLD2.setBounds(new Rectangle(30, 78, 83, 20));

        //listeners
        TXTFLD1.addPropertyChangeListener("value", new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent arg0) {
                TXTFLD2.setText(TXTFLD1.getText()+"set by change listener");
                //this doesnot work why ?
            }
        });
        BTN1.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                TXTFLD1.setText("Action Performed");
                //i what to set same value to TXTFLD2 using property change listener
            }
        });

        this.setContentPane(new Container());
        this.getContentPane().add(BTN1);
        this.getContentPane().add(TXTFLD1);
        this.getContentPane().add(TXTFLD2);
    }
}
```

Why the property change listener is not working.
What are the other alternatives solution for this problem?

Comment: Can they share the same underlying Document object? Then changes will automatically be mirrored.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For example, as StanislavL +1 suggested by using `DocumentListener`:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class TextLabelMirror {

    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    private JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
    private JTextField field1 = new JTextField(20);

    public TextLabelMirror() {
        field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateLabel(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateLabel(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateLabel(e);
            }

            private void updateLabel(DocumentEvent e) {
                java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        field1.setText(field.getText());
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 10, 0));
        mainPanel.add(field);
        mainPanel.add(field1);
    }

    public JComponent getComponent() {
        return mainPanel;
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextLabelMirror");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new TextLabelMirror().getComponent());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I had previously used the DocumentListener but without invokeLater().

Answer (score 5):

```
DocumentListener yourDocListener=...;
TXTFLD1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(yourDocListener);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should register a [document listener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) to it's document. Taken from [JTextField documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html):

> In the JTextComponent based
>   components, changes are broadcasted
>   from the model via a DocumentEvent to
>   DocumentListeners. The DocumentEvent
>   gives the location of the change and
>   the kind of change if desired. The
>   code fragment might look something
>   like:

```
 DocumentListener myListener = ??;
 JTextField myArea = ??;
 myArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(myListener);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the PropertyChangeListener with an ActionListener or DocumentListener.

Answer (score 1):

That's because there's no one firing property change events. Read up on [How to Write an Action Listener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html), although in order to trigger an action event, it is required that you press `Enter`. Otherwise, you'll need to read up on [How to Write a Document Listener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html).

Comment: @TalhaAhmedKhan `DocumentListener`

Answer (score 0):

Write this method instead of.

Replace TXTFLD1.addPropertyChangeListener with this method:

```
TXTFLD1.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {}
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        TXTFLD2.setText(TXTFLD1.getText());
    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {}
});
```

Comment: doesn't work with mouse edition (copy&paste, drag and drop text).