# How to sync a JLabel with a JTextField?

Tags: java, swing

I have no idea where to begin, I need to get the `JLabel` to be a clone of the `JTextField` as someone types into the `JTextField`.

I have no code on this so far as I have absolutely no clue on how to do code something that updates itself constantly.

Comment: you should had some code or pseudo-code in order to explain precisely what you re looking for , any related links or picture can also help .

Answer (score 1):

Check this

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html

The `DocumentListener` should allow you receive updates from a changing JTextField.

I think you just need to override the `changeUpdate` method

for example :

[Synchronize JTextFields Values by PropertyChangeListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492648/synchronize-jtextfields-values-by-propertychangelistener/6492802#6492802)

Answer (score 1):

You need do add a `DocumentListener` and update the `JLabel` whenever something was changed in the `JTextField`.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();

JTextField tf = new JTextField();
tf.addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener) {
    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        label.setText(tf.getText());
    }
    //...
});
```